# `preg_match` the Whole String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

This thing really confuses me, pardon my ignorance.

I have a var `$name` in here that I want to be free from number, I don't want any digit to be included in it. My `preg_match()` is this:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/[^\d]/',$name));
```

Test cases:

```
$name = "213131"; // int(0) 
$name = "asdda"; // int(1)
$name = "as232dda"; // int(1)
```

What I want is to have the third case to be `int(0)` too.

I'm really a hard time understanding this `preg_match()`, docs say it return 1 if a pattern match a subject. Here in my case, I use a negated class.

Comment: Before using regex, you _really_ need to learn the basics. A good place to start is: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Regexes are like a loaded weapon - if you don't understand how they work, you _will_ shoot yourself in the foot (or worse). The time spent learning them will pay for itself many times over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#3 matches because you have both letters and numbers.  Your regex in English basically says

> it matches if there is a non-digit character

If you want to match *only* non-digit characters, you have to have the regex match against the entire string and allow for an arbitrary number of characters:

```
^[^\d]+$
```

Comment: what does the first caret means before the character class?

Comment: @fishcracker, that matches the beginning of the string.  See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @fishcracker: `[^\d]` = `[\D]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex only checks that there is at least one non-digit.  Instead, you need to check that it is *only* non-digits:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^\D+$/',$name));
```

(`^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the string. `\D` means anything not a digit--the opposite of `\d`.  So this only matches non-digits from beginning to end.  It doesn't match an empty string.  Replace `+` with `*` if you want to match an empty string as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $string = "as232dda";
    $new_string = trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'',$string));
    echo $new_string;// gives 'asdda'
?>
```

Or function form:

```
<?php
  function remove_numbers($string){
    return(trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'',$string)));
  }

  $string = "as232dda";
  echo remove_numbers($string); // gives 'asdda'
?>
```